# How to install a Thawte SSL certificate on Amazon Elastic Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, amazon-elb

Here's my situation. We've generated an SSL certificate from Thawte for a site we're hosting on EC2. We have our servers load balanced using Elastic Load Balancer.

Thawte gives us one PKCS signed certificate. When I go to the Amazon console to generate a new load balancer so that I can attach the certificate it requires 4 fields:

```
Certificate Name
Private Key
Public Key
Certificate Chain
```

Where I'm getting confused is that we only have the 1 certificate, yet the private & public keys are expected to be different.

What's the process to complete this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Certificate name** is your choice - it is just to identify the certificate later
2. **Private Key** is the key (PEM, base-64) you generated when you created your CSR - you will copy and paste the entire file into the field, from `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` to `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` (inclusive).
3. **Public Key** is the PEM encoded, based 64 verion of what obtained from Thawte (X.509). Copy the contents of the X.509 into a text editor (e.g. vi), save it with a .cer extension. Use OpenSSL to display it in the needed format:

   ```
   openssl x509 -inform DER -in yourfilefromthawte.cer
   ```

   Copy and paste the output from `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` to `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` (inclusive) into the field.
4. **Certificate Chain** is the Thawte CA bundle that you can download from their site. For Thawte's SSL Web Server and Wildcard certificates (may be different if you have a different certificate type), their CA bundle is available from their [site](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=AR1374). (Download the 'Bundled CA version', it is already in PEM format, copy and paste the entire file (both certificates) into the field)

Check out [this AWS thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=53100) for more information (although that is Verizon specific, the basic ideas apply).

Answer (score 0):

A PKCS file is not a 'certificate', it is basically a bundle that typically includes the private key, certificate for your domain, and any possibly the CA certificate and any intermediate certificates.

Using openssl it is pretty easy to extract the various components of a PKCS12.  Plus there a few other tools that you can use to convert.  A search of [pkcs12 to pem](http://www.google.com/search?q=pkcs12%20to%20pem) should help you find a lot.

The command I run, when I need to do this is `openssl pkcs12 -in the file.pfx -out outputfile.txt -nodes`.  Then I manually break up outputfile.txt into the various keys/certs with a next editor.

Comment: That makes a little more sense. However I'm not sure if it gets me all the way there. On the Thawte console, I have the option to show the key as either PKCS #7 or X.509. Do I use the same process you described to extract the public/private keys from either of those documents?

Comment: Grab the X.509 download.  I haven't used Amazon, but I would bet that is the format you want.  I suspect the x.509 option will be a zip file with the various things separated.

Comment: Sadly its not a download. The literally provide a textarea with the x.509 key as copy/paste.

Comment: Amazon has instructions for setting up SSL on ELB: [http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/10/elastic-load-balancer-support-for-ssl-termination.html](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/10/elastic-load-balancer-support-for-ssl-termination.html)

Comment: @cyberx86 thanks, I already have the link. That's not the problem, its getting the 2 keys in order to fill the fields.